# Wordpress custom PHP AJAX call returns 400 Bad Request and does not execute

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to build a simple cookie banner that a user can close. Once the PHP sessions and cookies have been set (by accepting the cookies), the banner should disappear. However I keep getting a 400 bad request error.

jQUery:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery("#cookie-close").click(function(eve){  
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: ajax_var.url,
        data: "action=close_cookies&nonce="+ajax_var.nonce, 
        success: function(result){

             if(result == '1'){
             alert(result);
             jQuery('.cookie-banner').fadeOut();
             } // end if data

        }
    });
    eve.preventDefault();

    return false;
    });
});
```

functions.php:

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );


function my_enqueue() {
 wp_enqueue_script('close_cookies', get_template_directory_uri().'/scripts/js/ajax.js', '1.0', 1 );
 wp_localize_script('close_cookies', 'ajax_var', array(
 'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajaxnonce')
 ));
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_post_like', 'close_cookies' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_post_like', 'close_cookies' );

function close_cookies(){
$_SESSION["close_cookies"] = true;
setcookie("close_cookies", true, time() + 60, "/", "", "", TRUE);
echo '1';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cookie-banner">
<span id="cookie-close" class="btn btn-white-outlines">Accept</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You are passing the name of the PHP function as the `action` in your request parameters, but it needs to be the actual name of the action you added, so the part in the curly braces from `wp_ajax_{action_name}` resp. `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action_name}`

Comment: you can do this via javascript cookies

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in your js file:

```
data: "action=close_cookies&nonce="+ajax_var.nonce,
```

Change this by

```
data: {"action": "close_cookies", "nonce":ajax_var.nonce},
```

Change following two lines

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_post_like', 'close_cookies' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_post_like', 'close_cookies' );
```

by

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_close_cookies', 'close_cookies' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_close_cookies', 'close_cookies' );
```

You get that response because ajax doesn't found the action you're passing. Above should work for you.